# Passing text to TextField from tableview cell swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application that displays data in tableview cell and not I want to be able to call the `addText viewcontroller` when I select the cell and I want to pass the text value in the cell to the text field in the `addText viewcontroller`

below is what I have tried but the app crashes everytime I select the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let list = items?[indexPath.row]

        print("SELECTED ROW \(list?.name)")

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "AddListSB", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.ADD_LIST_SB) as! AddListVC

       newViewController.titleTxtField.text = list.title

        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

it prints the right text in the console though before crashing and does not give the Viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `newViewController.loadViewIfNeeded()` before setting the text on the label to make sure the view is loaded.

If this doesn't solve the issue, then the outlets might not be set properly on the view controller.

Comment: kindly help check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296851/updating-values-in-a-realm-database-swift

Answer (score 2):

The crash because the vc isn't yet loaded

```
newViewController.sendedText = list.title
```

//

```
class AddListVC:UIViewController {
   var sendedText = ""
}
```

and set the string inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: the `sendedText` should be in the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: thanks I think @John West approach is a more direct solution and it works

Comment: kindly help check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296851/updating-values-in-a-realm-database-swift