# How do I update my Realm Variable when I click on a button?

Tags: swift, xcode, filter, realm

Hi I'm trying to change the variable 'category' from an object called 'book' in realm with the following code:

```
                  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reading", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
                try! realm.write {
                     let category = "reading"
                            let book = Book()
                            book.category = category
                   }
              }
```

When I checked in mangoDB realm studio the object category has not been updated. The tutorials I looked at used the same function. This is the whole updated code:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    func showmethisfunction() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let boook = Book()
        
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Want to put your book in a list?", message: "Please Select an Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Read", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
                 try! realm.write
                {
                    boook.category = "read"
                   }
              }))

              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Want to read", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
                try! realm.write {
                    boook.category = "wanttoread"
                   }
              }))

              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reading", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
                try! realm.write {
                    let category = "reading"
                    boook.category = category
                   }
              }))

              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: { (_) in
                  print("User click Dismiss button")
              }))

              self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                  print("completion block")
              })
    }
showmethisfunction()
}
```

I used a similiar alert controller to add a book manually, and that worked, it just doesn't work when I want to add a variable from a book

Comment: The code in your question is pretty much correct. My guess is that you're opening the wrong .realm file with Realm Studio so you're not seeing the updates. Also you've got two different variables in the question `boook` and `book` which could lead to confusion. When you do this `let book = Book()` it's going to create a brand new book object and not update an existing one.

Comment: The code is actually supposed to update an existing variable because it is triggered when I tap on a tableview cel. I also tried this out with my segmented control and it doesn't work, how do I change the code into updating an existing book?

Comment: If I got the comment right I. have to use : let book = realm.objects(Book.self).  but then I get the following error Value of type 'Results<Book>' has no member 'category'

Comment: Well, yes and no. This code `let book = realm.objects(Book.self)` does not read a book object - the variable would be better represented as `bookResults` as it will read ALL of the book objects. The error you're getting is because Results objects do not have a `category` parameter - only a single book object has that property.  I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First get your object which one you can update.
I'm given example using filter. You can use any.

```
do {
     let realm = try Realm()
     let book = realm.objects(Book.self).filter({ $0.id == id }).first
        try realm.write {
            book?.category = category
        }
    } catch { }
```

Or get idea from this link
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/swift/latest/index.html#models

Go to **Auto-updating objects** section in above link.

I updated my answer after updated your question.
Replace line
`let boook = Book()` with this line
`let boook = realm.objects(Book.self).first ?? Book()`

Comment: if I use                      let book = realm.objects(Book.self)
before write I get the error saying : Value of type 'Results<Book>' has no member 'category'. Eventhough I checked in Realm Studio and it defintely has a value for category..

Comment: @Mischa This answer doesn't really have anything to do with the question. It is correct in showing how to read in an *existing* book object and then update a property, but the code is your question is instantiating a new book object with `let book = Book()` and then updating a property, which is correct. e.g. This answer isn't wrong, but not an answer to your question as the code in your question is correct.

Comment: This is going to be problematic. Realm objects are unordered and getting the 'first' object could be any number of objects that have a matching id. This `realm.objects(Book.self).first` would be even worse because it will get *any* object from Realm - just depends on what it considers *first* at that moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

To restate the question:

> How do I updated a property on an existing object

There are a number of different ways to do that and some of the answer depends on the object model.

Generally speaking, most objects would have some unique identifier called the *primary key* and if you know that identifier, updating the object is a snap

```
class PersonClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var name = "Jay"

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}
```

The ObjectId will generate a unique _id for every object when it's instantiated. If you know the primary key, you can update an object like this

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.create(PersonClass.self, value: ["id": "1", "name": "Jay 2"], update: .modified)
}
```

This assumes the existing object you want to update has a primary key of "1" and will update the object's name property to Jay 2

You can also read the object in via the primary key to then update it

```
if let jay = realm.object(ofType: PersonClass.self, forPrimaryKey: "1") {
    try! realm.write {
        jay.name = "Jays new name"
    }
}
```

lastly you can run a query to get *an* object with a matching property as well (but don't do this)

```
if let jay = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).filter("name == 'Jay'").first {
    try! realm.write {
        jay.name = "Jays new name"
    }
}
```

This last option is generally a bit 'dangerous' as it will filter for all PersonClass objects with the name of 'Jay' and the results will be unordered so the `first` one could be different at different times... so the key here is 'don't do it this way'.

As a side note per the above, realm results are unordered unless you specify the `.sorted(byKeyPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the existing object without creating primary key in RealmSwift.

1. Create the keys of the Realm Object.

import Foundation
import RealmSwift

final class ModelRealM: Object {

```
@objc dynamic var message = String()
@objc dynamic var type = String()
```

}

2. In ViewController create array variable of type (var arrData : Results!)

class ChattingVC: UIViewController {

let chattingVM = ChattingVM()

let realm = try! Realm()

var arrData : Results!

```
//MARK: - View Life Cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    arrData = realm.objects(ModelRealM.self)
    var model = ModelRealM()
    
    model.message = "ABC"
    model.type = "Text"
    
    self.chattingVM.saveData(model) { isDone in
        
        if isDone{
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return chattingVM.realm.objects(ModelRealM.self).count
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let type = arrData?[indexPath.row].type else{
        
        print("------------No Data found------------")
        return UITableViewCell()
        
    }
    if type == "Receiver"{
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReceiverCell", for: indexPath) as! ReceiverCell
        cell.model = arrData?[indexPath.row]
        cell.editBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.editBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.editReceiverBtn(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
        
    }else{
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SenderCell", for: indexPath) as! SenderCell
        cell.model = arrData?[indexPath.row]
        cell.editBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.editBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.editReceiverBtn(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
        
    }
    
}

@objc func editReceiverBtn(sender:UIButton){
    
    self.txtView.text = "" //Write the updated message in TxtView and pass in this function.
    self.chattingVM.updateReamObject(index: sender.tag, msg: self.txtView.text) { isTrue in
        
        if isTrue{
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

}

3. In View Model Update Function is used to update

class ChattingVM{

```
//MARK: - Variables
let realm = try! Realm()

//MARK: -
//MARK: - Save Data to Realm
func saveData(_ data : ModelRealM,completion:@escaping(_ isDone: Bool) -> Void){
   
    do{
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(data)
        }
    }catch{
        print("Error in saving data :- \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    completion(true)
    
}


//MARK: -
//MARK: - Update Data
func updateReamObject(index:Int,msg:String,completion:@escaping(_ isTrue:Bool) -> Void){
    
    do{
        try realm.write {
            realm.objects(ModelRealM.self)[index].message = msg
        }
    }catch{
        print("Error in saving data :- \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    completion(true)
    
}
```

}